# Need help in selecting a suitable reporting platform

Tags: data-visualization, data-analysis, reporting, business-intelligence

We are using "https://chartio.com/" for our reporting purposes and now it it's been adopted by Atlassian we are planning to go for another flexible and reliable business intelligence and reporting platform.

So i would like to ask the tech community on suggestions on platforms that we need to select.
What we are looking for is,

1. Reliability
2. Flexibility
3. Powerful data management and manipulating capacity
4. Ability to connect data from different sources
5. Link sharing ability
6. High Security & Role access
7. Good visualisation capability

We have few in our plan already like,

1. https://www.holistics.io/
2. Tableau

Would need your suggestions on this.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Bold BI](http://www.boldbi.com) and [Bold Reports](http://www.boldreports.com) are options to consider.

[image: Bold BI]

- Reliability - Yes
- Flexibility - Yes
- Powerful data management and manipulating capacity - Yes.
- Ability to connect data from different sources [Integrations](https://www.boldbi.com/embedded/integrations)
- Link sharing ability - [Yes](https://help.boldbi.com/embedded-bi/visualizing-data/working-with-widgets/linking-urls-and-dashboards/)
- High Security & Role access [Yes](https://help.boldbi.com/embedded-bi/working-with-dashboards/share-dashboards/manage-permissions/)
- Good visualisation capability [Yes](https://help.boldbi.com/embedded-bi/visualizing-data/visualization-widgets/)

Note: I work for Syncfusion (Bold BI).

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of details that distinguish the various options available (Power BI, Sisense, QlikSense, Datapine, DBxtra, QueryTree, KNIME, RapidMiner, Orange), some of which may be make-or-break for you.  Only you will know that, so you probably should evaluate these in some detail yourself.  However, I will recommend Orange (https://orangedatamining.com/) as a tool that is focused on analytics more than reporting, if that's an aspect that's important to you.